# CSS border getting clipped on retina display

Tags: html, css, retina-display, retina

[image: clipped border]Depending on the width of the browser window the border of some elements like this deposit button get clipped. When I resize the width of the browser, if I move it pixel by pixel the border is clipped and then unclipped with each pixel move, so maybe it has something to do with even/odd pixels on a retina display since there are two real pixels per css pixel? I have a 15" retina macbook pro at 1680x1050.

here's the SCSS for the button:

```
.make-deposit {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid $green;
    color: $green;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;

    &:hover {
        background-color: $green;
        color: $white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try add the box-sizing: border-box; CSS Rule...

Try this new code:

```
.make-deposit {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid $green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: $green;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}
.make-deposit:hover {
        background-color: $green;
        color: $white;
}
```

Comment: Turns out this button was inheriting overflow: hidden from styles I had for all buttons. I set it to overflow: visible and it fixed the issue but I'm still unsure why I need to do that